# Clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I used **hclust** to cluster my data and **cutree** to specify the numbers of cluster to be 3. Is there any way that I can examine each of the cluster? By examine I mean to list out the cases/observations that are in e.g. the first cluster. I tried all the basic function that I know such as **summary(), list()**...but seem not relevant. Any function can do this?

If not, the cutree function returns a list of groups/clusters that each of my observation belongs to, something like this:

1,3,1,2,3,3,1

which indicates my first observation belongs to group 1, second belong to group three...
I am thinking about how to extract the position from that list where e.g. group = 1, so it will return 1,3 and 7 since observations 1,3,7 are belong to group 1

Or I need to use a loop to count all the observations that belong to e.g. group 1 from that list?

Is my question clear?

Comment: No your question is not very clear, but In an attempt to answer.  You have the list from the cutree function: 1,3,1,2,3,3,1, you can use this array to subset or group your original data frame in order to examine the individual clusters.   FYI: Providing an example(data and output goes a long way in obtaining help in this forum.

Comment: I made it, thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Does this help to get started?

```
nclust <- 10 

cutreeout <- cutree(hclustOutput, nclust)
```

Add them  as a new column to your dataframe

```
mydata$cluster <- cutreeout
```

How many observations are in each cluster?

```
table(mydata$cluster)
```

Then you can do more stuff to interpret your clusters, and/or study subsets of your data.

Answer (score -1):

This is a hint, not the answer. Here's the example of [Hierarchical Clustering in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/hierarchical-clustering-in-r-2/). You can try to use the functions `table()`, `ggplot()` in order to see observations per clusters.